# Требования к системе для Win Phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

Вопрос прост: действительно ли для Windows Phone 8 можно разрабатывать только из под Win 8?

---

*Это просто epic fail какой-то! Везде установлена Windows 7 и я не могу писать под Windows Phone 8???? 
Android - наше все!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Минимальные требования для работы эмулятора и Windows Phone SDK 8, увы не порадовали: Win 8 Pro х64 и поддержка процессором технологии виртуализации, ибо эмулятор использует Hyper-V. У меня лично процессор не новый(Dual Core), но эмулятор так и не запустился.

Вообщем, одно разочарование:(